# RE problems that are neither RE-complete nor recursive

Tags: computational-complexity

As stated, is there any decision problems in the complexity class RE that are neither RE-complete nor recursive?

It seems that almost all of nonrecursive RE problems are in RE-complete...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is known as [Post's problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post%27s_problem#Post.27s_problem_and_the_priority_method) and the answer is yes. The first such problem (and the only one I am familiar with) was constructed using forcing and the method of finite injury.